# Infinite norm of two randomly picked points

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Let X and Y be points in the 4000-dimensional unit cube, picked at random with uniform distribution (all locations in the cube are equally likely). $X \in [0,1]^{ 4000}$ and $Y \in [0,1]^{4000}$.

Why $ \|X −Y\|_{\infty}$ is very likely to be close to 1?
I also wonder how the 1 and 2-norms of $X-Y$ look like.

Answer (score 0):

$\|X-Y\|_{\infty}=\max_{1\leq i\leq 4000}|X_i-Y_i|$ where $X_i,Y_i\sim\text{ iid } U[0,1].$

Then you can get the explicit distribution for $X_i-Y_i$ whose range would be between $[-1,1].$ Now define  for $t>0$ $p_t=P(|X_i-Y_i|>t)=2P(X_i-Y_i>t)=(1-t)^2.$ Then $P(\|X-Y\|_{\infty}>t)=1-(1-p_t)^{4000}=1-(1-(1-t^2))^{4000}=1-(2t-t^2)^{4000}$ which is close to 1 even for $t$ being close to 1. And the probability is zero for t=1. So, $\|X-Y\|_\infty$ is very close to 1. $\frac1{4000}\|X-Y\|_1=\frac1{4000}\sum_{i=1}^{4000}|X_i-Y_i|\approx E|X_1-Y_1|$ by SLLN. So, $\|X-Y\|_1\approx 4000 E|X_1-Y_1|.$ By similar logic $\|X-Y\|_2\approx \sqrt{4000}E(X_1-Y_1)^2.$ Of course these are just intutive calculation, not regorous. If you want actual behaviours of them then you need to Bennet's inequality to get non-asymptotic bound on probability.